# PHP Object undefined property

Tags: php, object

I am trying to access to this object $results, and I can't figure out why the first echo and the print_r give me the expected output, but the last echo gives me the error "Undefined property".

```
 foreach($results as $number => $hotel){
     echo $number;
     print_r($hotel);
     echo $results->{$number};
 }
```

-----------------------------------**Better explanation**---------------------------------

I noticed that you need some other informations to help me, so:

$results is an object containing results of a query: it contains a lis of hotels (objects) and everyone of them is descripted by some fields->value.
In order to modify this object (delete one hotel from the object $results) I was looking for the method to reference an item of the object $results, and I thought that the way was $results->{$number}

So the thing that i really want to do is:

```
foreach($results as $number => $hotel){
    foreach($hotel as $field => $value) {
        if($field == 'id' && $value == '18'){
            // here I wanna delete the hotel from the object $results
            // but unset($results->{$number}) doesn't work.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can debug the third 'object'.

Comment: Try using `$results[$number]`. You are using a foreach which probably means you are using an array.

Comment: you don't need to echo the print_r

Comment: @Jerodev: that gives me the error  Error: Cannot use object of type[..]as array

Comment: @CodingInsane: Yes, i'm too tired today, i fix it :D

Comment: What is `$results` an object of?

Comment: Why do you echo a property of $results after you are using a foreach? It makes no sense? What do you want to get exactly?

Comment: @divaka Now I explained it all. Sorry for the incompleteness of my first question, I was just trying to semplify the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach as you show is normaly use with an array. So to access the items you need to use the good operator that is []
In the foreach the $number is the key , the $hotel are items in the array.

So to acces an hotel you need $result[$number]